# OleDb connection to an Access database

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, connection-string

I've been trying to write to a database and save to the file but I cant get it to work, can't tell why either.

The error I get is:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' in System.Data.dll
```

Additional information:

```
Could not find installable ISAM.
```

Here's the Code I'm running, any help/advice would be greatly appreciated

```
    private void BtnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OleDbConnection Conn = new OleDbConnection();
        Conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =| DataDirectory |\\HoliPlanData.accdb; Trusted_Connection = True;";

        String PayrollNo = TxtPayroll.Text;
        String FirstName = TxtFirstName.Text;
        String LastName = TxtLastName.Text;            
        String AnnualHolidayEntitlemet = TxtAHE.Text;
        String DaysTakenToDate = TxtDTTD.Text;

        OleDbCommand Query = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Employee (PayrollNo, FirstName, LastName, AnnualHolidayEntitlement, DaysTakenToDate) Values(@PayrollNo, @FirstName, @LastName, @AnnualHolidayEntitlement, @DaysTakenToDate");
        Query.Connection = Conn;

        Conn.Open(); //THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR OCCURS IN CODEPROSSESS

        if (Conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            Query.Parameters.Add("@PayrollNo", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = PayrollNo;
            Query.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = FirstName;
            Query.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = LastName;
            Query.Parameters.Add("@AnnualHolidayEntitlement", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = AnnualHolidayEntitlemet;
            Query.Parameters.Add("@DaysTakenToDate", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DaysTakenToDate;

            try
            {
                Query.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Data Added Successfully");
                Conn.Close();                    
            }
            catch (OleDbException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                Conn.Close();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Failed");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two issues:

1. Your connection string has an extra semicolon as you pointed out in comments above
2. Your INSERT query is missing the last parenthesis )

Compare these lines:

```
OleDbCommand Query = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Employee (PayrollNo, FirstName, LastName, AnnualHolidayEntitlement, DaysTakenToDate) Values(@PayrollNo, @FirstName, @LastName, @AnnualHolidayEntitlement, @DaysTakenToDate");
OleDbCommand Query = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Employee (PayrollNo, FirstName, LastName, AnnualHolidayEntitlement, DaysTakenToDate) Values(@PayrollNo, @FirstName, @LastName, @AnnualHolidayEntitlement, @DaysTakenToDate)");
```

Comment: Joe, you brilliant person. Thank you so much. Have a brilliant day!!

Answer (score 0):

Install [AccessDatabaseEngine](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=13255) and try again.

Change the connection string as below.

`Conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;DataSource=|DataDirectory|\\HoliPlanData.accdb;Trusted_Connection = True;";`

Comment: Tried both of the above, still getting the same error. Does anyone know the problem?